# Binding ItemsSources ListBox directly From DataBase WPF C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, itemssource

I have binded my ItemsSource ListBox for a property of ViewModel, this property is an ObservableCollection who i like displaying my List of role from Table USRROL, this is my XAML :

```
<ListBox Name="ListRoles" 
         Background="White" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListeRole, IsAsync=True}"                 
         DisplayMemberPath=role
         BorderBrush="white" Width="120" 
         FontSize="11"    
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

and this is my property :

```
ObservableCollection<String> _listeRole = new ObservableCollection<String>            ();
public ObservableCollection<String> ListeRole
{
    get { return _listeRole ; }
    set { _listeRole = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ListeRole"); }
}
public CollectionViewSource CvsListeRole = new CollectionViewSource();
ConstructeurviewModel() { _listeRole = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    CvsListeRole.Source = _listeRole ;
    FiltresStatutActifsView = CvsFiltresStatut.View;
}
```

And in my Model i have instancied my value

```
  public string role {get;set;}
```

For information, this code did not work, can anyone tell me the mistake please?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the output window? Is the DataContext set to your ConstructeurviewModel ?

Comment: Fill your `_listeRole`  in constructor or After filling `_listeRole`  call `RaisePropertyChanged("ListeRole");`

Comment: show ur code behind. are u setting data context as VM instance ?